# What is the last part of this inequation called

Tags: terminology, linear-programming

In an mixed integer optimization model, contraints like this often occur:
$$\sum_{j \in J} x_{ij} \leq a_i \; \forall i \in I$$
In this example, $J$ and $I$ might be index sets of customers and factories, respectively. $x_{ij}$ can be a binary variable and $a_i$ an (integer) parameter. This, forexample could be a capacity constraint where factory $i \in I$ can only serve $a_i$ customers. $x_{ij} = 1$, iff customer $j \in J$ is assinged to factory $i \in I$. This, of course, holds for all factories ($\forall i \in I$). I am looking for the technical term to refer to this last part $\forall i \in I$.

Comment: The last part states "for all $i$ in $I$", using the universal quantifier, denoted $\forall$.

Comment: Actually, we are searching for a name like "domain" or something comparable...

Comment: You might be refering to $I$, which probably is an Index Set.

Comment: Yes, I and J are index sets

Comment: I would add more context to your question, if it's a specific technical term you are looking for :)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I edit the question

Comment: "constraint indices"